# How to "jump" commit over a merge?

Tags: git

I have the following commits:

```
-A----B---m---D        [branch_1]
   \     /
    --C--              [branch_2]
```

And now I want to move B commit *after* the merge commit *m*, like this:

```
-A--------m'---B'---D' [branch_1]
  \     /
   --C--               [branch_2]
```

How to reach that state? In fact, I need to change the order of B and m.

I've tried `git rebase -i HEAD~x`, but it grabs more commits than I want to replay.

Comment: I would suggest something like, reset branch_1 to A, merge branch_2 in, cherry pick B, then cherry pick D. (branch_2 will be unaffected)

Comment: In the desired result, is C the only commit between A and the merge commit or are there other commits that you did not show? And if there are not, do you insist in having a merge commit?

Comment: @j6t good point. A merge commit really doesn't make much sense in that case. I hope OP can clarify

Comment: @j6t, in my real case, C, B and D are the groups of commits, and I don't really care about having a merge commit (but I thought there's some easy way to "move" it). So, I've just made a temproary branch from A, merged C in and then cherry-picked B and D groups of commits, and then I reset branch_1 to A and fast-forwarded it to temporary branch - as evolutionxbox told. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Then `git rebase C branch_1` would have been the easiest way. What you did is basically the manual version of that.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This can be done, but the chance for conflicts which need to be resolve manually is high.

You need to recreate the merge commit with different parents, then cherry-pick/rebase all required commits.

Make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes or stash them before running the commands.

We start with your original history graph:

```
-A----B---m---D        < branch_1
   \     /
    --C--              < branch_2
```

First, we move branch_1 to commit A:

```
git checkout -B branch_1 A # move branch_1 to commit A
```

```
    --B-----m---D
   /       /
-A-       /            < branch_1 
   \     /
    --C--              < branch_2
```

Then, branch_2 is merged into branch_1 (recreating the merge commit; you might need to manually resolve conflicts at this step):

```
git merge --no-ff branch_2 # recreate the merge commit
```

```
    --B-----m---D
   /       /
-A-       /
   \     /
    --C--              < branch_2
     \   \
      ----m'           < branch_1
```

And finally pick the desired commits:

```
git cherry-pick B D        # copy commits B and D
```

```
    --B-----m---D
   /       /
-A-       /
   \     /
    --C--              < branch_2
     \   \
      ----m'--B'--D'   < branch_1
```

Because the old commits became unreachable, the resulting history graph looks like:

```
-A---C--              < branch_2
   \    \
     ----m'--B'--D'   < branch_1
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that @knittl is using a sequence of operations to get it done... I didn't check it with a magnifying glass to see if it works but I do see that I would use a different approach.

First, create a *temporary* branch on top of m:

```
git checkout -b blah m
```

Then, revert `B` on top of this:

```
git revert B
```

When this is wrapped up, we *know* that this work tree is what it would look like to merge the two current parents of `m` _if you remove `B`... we will use this branch later on.

Now, take the parent branch of `m` that includes `B` and remove it from its history.... let's suppose it is `m^2` (to be read as `the second parent`) that has `B` in it:

```
git checkout B~
git cherry-pick B..m^2
```

I am assuming the branch was a straight line and that's why I used a cherry-pick there.

Now, `@` (to be read as **where we are standing**) will be the second parent of the new `m` so let's create a new merge commit (will use a different *temporary* branch for this) that uses the tree from `blah` as its content, instead of `m`.

```
git checkout -b new-merge $( git commit-tree -p m~ -p @ -m "Here is the new improved M" blah^{tree} )
```

I am using `m~` and `@` as the parents because `B` was in the second parent.... if B was in the first parent instead, you would use `@` and `m^2` as the parents there.

Now, we can apply `B` after the new merge:

```
git cherry-pick B
```

**If there are conflicts when you run that cherry-pick**, leverage `m` to get the resulting working tree without having to go through the conflicts.... unless you have other funky things in mind, of course: `git restore --staged --worktree --source m -- .; git cherry-pick --continue`.

And we can apply all the other things that made up the old branch past `m`:

```
git cherry-pick m..branch-1
```

Again, assuming it is a straight line.

If you like the result, force-place branch-1 on top of the second temporary branch:

```
git branch -f branch-1 new-merge
```

And now you can delete the 2 temporary branches we created during the journey.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -r -i <commit-A>
```

`git rebase` is a command used to re-write history.
`-i` specifies an interactive rebase.
`-r` specifies that merge commits should be kept. (Default for rebase is to remove merge commits.)

Then edit the list of commits and move commit B to where you want it:  after the merge and before commit D

Note:  You may have to resolve conflicts depending on the changes made in the commits.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout A                 # back to the last good branch_1 commit
git merge branch_2             # do the merge you wanted (may want --no-ff here?)
git cherry-pick B              # cherry-pick the commit you wanted here
git rebase --onto @ branch_1   # rebase the rest of branch_1 onto the corrected base
```